# CORS (cross origin resource sharing) using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, apache, cors

i just followed PHP header of CORS and i have a strange behavior here i create a two simple pages 
one page (content.php) using port 1112 and the other page which (sample.html) using port 1113 in my local machine 
and i noticed strange behavior 
sample.html trying to retrieve information from  content.php
here is the code for both pages 
sample.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    function makerequest(serverPage, objID) {
        var obj = document.getElementById(objID);
        xmlhttp.open("POST", serverPage);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                obj.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<body onload="makerequest ('http://localhost:1112/content.php','hw')">
<div align="center">
<h1>Sample</h1>
<div id="hw"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the other page 
content.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:1113/sample.html");
?>
<title>page1</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 770px; text-align: left; color: green;">
<h1>Page 1</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod?
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, ?
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.?
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu ?
fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in?
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

now when i am trying to run sample.html using chrome & firefox it's blocked even if i give in the header the origin link 
and if i run it using IE it's work 
to make it work i need to give the header ( * ) which different from what i want to do 
i tried to figure out why it's not working as i want in chrome and firefox

here is the error message i get it from chrome 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:1112/content1.php. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:1113/sample.html' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost:1113' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Unfortunately I believe you will get CORS issues no matter what with localhost, consider trying the local IP instead. Also, you may need to actually configure your webserver to send the headers, CORS is some picky stuff.  Also, for Chrome you need these addtional headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers and Access-Control-Allow-Methods.

Comment: does CORS only affect localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes to your code:

File: content.php

```
<?php
//header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:1113/sample.html");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:1113");
```

?>

It should work.

The definition of same origin as enforced by SOP (and that CORS helps bypass) is: "Two pages have the same origin if the protocol, port, and host are the same for both pages.".

In your code, you are supposed to add the CORS header to reflect the origin  that can be allowed by the browser to display the contents of "content.php" *hence you have to specify the "origin" as the header value and that is http://localhost:1113 (not 'http://localhost:1113/sample.html')*.

Also, the statement "Unfortunately I believe you will get CORS issues no matter what with localhost, consider trying the local IP instead." in Fredo's answer is not correct. The browser will treat [**scheme+host+port**] in totality when determining the origin. So, using localhost with different port numbers should be treated as different origins without any issue.

Comment: actually now i figure out if i just make the header as the following it's working fine 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:1113");
that's what i figure out using your method in the article you wrote it and now it's work fine 
thanks again dear Gaurab for your care

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these headers:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With"

"Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST"
```

It might also help to add this as a server method rather than via the page in PHP, if apache either in your httpd.conf or in .htaccess.

This answer was derived from this blog post (using node.js / express) http://williambert.online/2013/06/allow-cors-with-localhost-in-chrome/

Comment: now i used your headers and it's the same result there is nothing change 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:1113/sample.html");

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With");

header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST");

Comment: where's DELETE ?

Answer (score 0):

```
You may add following lines in  .htaccess code where you have palce sample.html

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

OR

```
 In sample.html file add below headers on top.

 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
```

Comment: without adding any header in the htaccess it's working i just define the vhost in the apache and it's work fine now thanks again for your answer